# Como mostrar datos de una pila Stack

Tags: java, stack

Lo que quiero hacer yo es mostrar los datos de la Pila Stack en forma de texto porque estoy haciendo el obj.get(i) pero se me ve en forma de numero y quiero que se me muestre en forma de texto!

package examenpruebas;

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

/**
 *
 * @author Pol-Pc
 */
public class ExamenPruebas {


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan  = new Scanner (System.in);


        Stack obj = new Stack();
         datos libros = new datos();
        boolean salir = false;
        int opciones; 

        // TODO code application logic here

        while(!salir){

            System.out.println("--------------Bienvenidos a la Libreria----------------------");
            System.out.println("1.- Apilar Libro");
            System.out.println("2.- Desapilar Libro");
            System.out.println("3.- Consultar Libro");
            System.out.println("4.- Salir");

            System.out.println("Indicame la Opcion que quiere realizar: ");
            opciones = scan.nextInt();

            switch (opciones){

             case 1:

                    System.out.println("[AUTOR]: ");
                    String autor = scan.next();

                    System.out.println("[TITULO]: ");
                    String titulo = scan.next();

                    System.out.println("[FECHA]: ");
                    String fecha = scan.next();

                    libros.setAutor(autor);
                    libros.setFecha(fecha);
                    libros.setTitulo(titulo);


                    System.out.println("Se ha apilado correctamente.");

                    obj.push(libros);

             case 2:     

                    for(int i = 0; i<obj.size(); i++){                       
                        System.out.println(obj.get(i));               
                   }                    
           } 

       }

    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor podrias editar la pregunta y específicar cual es el problema que estás encontrando?

Comment: Es para mostrar los datos de un stack en forma de texto.

Answer (score 1):

Con `obj.get(i)` retornas el objeto `datos` que está en la posición `i` del `Stack` `obj`.

Cuando haces `System.out.println(obj.get(i));`, estás pasándole a `println()` un objeto `datos` (no un `String`), por lo tanto implícitamente, lo que se imprime es obj.get(i).toString().

Para imprimir los datos del libro, tenés dos caminos:

1) Hacer un `@Override` de `toString()` en la clase `datos`:

```
public class datos{
 // todo lo que esta actualmente en la clase
 // ....

 @Override
 public String toString(){
    return getTitulo() + " / " + getFecha() + " / " + getAutor();
 }
}
```

2) Modificar la salida dentro del `for`, haciendo un `System.out.println()` por cada atributo.

```
for(int i = 0; i<obj.size(); i++){                       
    System.out.println(obj.get(i).getTitulo());
    System.out.println(obj.get(i).getFecha());
    System.out.println(obj.get(i).getAutor());    
    System.out.println("");         
}
```

Algunas notas al margen:

Para las variables, clases, y métodos usa nombres que describan lo que son.
`obj` sería más representativo si se llamara `stack`, `libros` o `stackDeLibros`.
Sería más fácil entender que la clase `datos` en realidad representa un libro si se llamara `Libro`. Y la variable `libros`, que en realidad es un libro,  si se llamara `libro` (en singular).

Por convención los nombres de las clases en Java comienzan con Mayúscula y las variables y atributos con minúscula.

**EDIT I:**

Una cosa más, dentro del `switch (opciones){`, normalmente al final de cada `case:` se coloca un break para evitar que se procese lo que está dentro de los `case:` sucesivos. 
Veo que en tu código el break está faltando, por lo tanto cuando se ejecuta la el `case:1` también se ejecuta el `case:2`.
Si querés evitar este comportamiento tenés que agregar el `break`.

Comment: La Opcion dos Juan no me sale los gets de la clase de datos...

Comment: Podés agregar la clase `datos` a la pregunta?